# UTF Files and strings in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, utf

I'm writing a small application that must read files in any Unicode format (UTF-8, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE, UTF-32LE) into UTF-32 strings, and then manipulate them.

Is there any open source library that offers functionality similar to "string" and "fstream" (or "cstdio" and "cstring") but with full unicode support? Or an easy way to do it with the standard one?

I'd like the solution to be portable.

Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks in advance.

Lodovico

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901473/read-unicode-files-c

Comment: @Tim Well, wstring_t functions are not portable and they (usually) deal only with UTF-16LE. I updated my question. Thanks anyway for the quick reply.

Comment: http://site.icu-project.org/  but the question is off topic because you are asking for library recommendations

Comment: C++ can do that with no extra libraries: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/codecvt (although if you need more than just conversions between the UTFs, then you're going to need icu and boost.locale)

Comment: @Cubbi and David Hefferman Thanks for your comments. What I need exactly are hashes, substrings and length in term of unicode codepoints. That's why IMB ICU is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: see utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 0):

You will find this class useful CTextFileDocument - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7958/CTextFileDocument

I have been using this for many years. The "About the code" section says that it has been made platform independent.

It is mainly for files. But you will be able to just copy related code to handle strings also.